# form serialize does not work when using it in the .submit function

Tags: jquery, ajax

When serializing the form data in the chrome console or using the form serialize in a .onClick function it works but it doesnt when it is serializing the form data in a .submit function

i've checked all the input field and they all have the "Name" tag. i've printed the serialize form data from chromes console and it returns all the data from the form.

```
$('#assetForm').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        data: $('#assetForm').serialize(),
        url:'updateAsset.php',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```

expected to get the whole form data but it returns nothing. This is what it returned.
[Alerting data from .submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUoaV.png)

Comment: Does the form exist when that code runs? Your alert is inside success callback...is that the alert shown in image? If so that is the response data. I doubt serialize() is a problem. Sounds like something else

Comment: The `data` in `success:function(data)` is *not* the same as the `data` in `data:$("form").serialize()` - add a line after `e.preventDefault()` : `console.log($("#assetForm").serialize();` and check your console.

Comment: Other than the `alert(data)` in your code, what makes you think that it's not working?

Comment: @charlietfl yeah the form already exist when the code runs

Comment: @freedomn-m the code you gave worked! it gave me the form's data. So im guessing there some problem in the php file? Also, thanks for clarifying about the data thing.

Comment: I found the problem, There was an error in my PHP. Thanks for the help